# How to retrieve data from very large JSON quickly and efficiently

Tags: json, react-native, axios, fetch

I have this json: https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json (warning, it is very large). I am finding that when I am making a request with `axios`, it is taking a very long time to receive the response. Is there any other way I could fetch this data more quickly?

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const {
      data: { AFG },
    } = await axios.get(
      "https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json"
    );

    const dataArray = AFG.data.slice(-7);
    return dataArray;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setData(await fetchData());
    };

    fetchAPI();
  }, [setData]);
```

Answer (score 0):

according to the dicussion here: https://twitter.com/mrousavy/status/1502311685729701891 RN fetch and axios is not the fastest, but you would need to try other libraries to see the difference. If you need only partial data you could implement your own native fetch with analyzing the partial data during download, but this you would need to develop yourself.

Comment: axios works perfectly fine for smaller sized json objects and I can get a fast response. The problem occurs only for larger json objects.